# Transform the fields I received from my soap response, to match the fields in the JSON object

Tags: xml, json, soap

I have a question regarding how I should go about taking the response from a soap call, and passing it to a JSON object.

Let me lay out the situation first:

First I am sending an xml based request to a soap based web service. I am receiving the response back in xml format, and I want to be able to pass this response to a JSON object, and on the way transform the fields I received from my soap response, to match the fields in the JSON object.

For example, I might have

```
<FirstName>Bob<FirstName>
```

as a field in my soap response, but I need to transform that to a fit a variable called "First" in my JSON object.

Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated, I am new to all of these technologies and have been getting by mostly with basic tutorials and expanding them to what I need so far, but have become stuck at this point. If any more clarification is needed I can do so!

Comment: Can you give a little more detail on your technology stack? Are you trying to transform the service call in another service in javascript?

Comment: Sure thing. Basically we are have our own set of webservices which return JSON object responses. Outside sources send in the request and we return them those objects. But the point of storage with the information is another outside source of webservices that are built on SOAP. So we must send xml formatted soap requests to them and recieve their response. So the response from them in XML format needs to be transformed back into JSON so we can pass that back as a resposne on our end. This is all Java based

Answer (score 1):

There are some standard ways to convert from XML to JSON ([Parker convention](http://code.google.com/p/xml2json-xslt/wiki/TransformingRules), [Badgerfish](http://www.sklar.com/badgerfish/) or using [JsonML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JsonML) etc) but they work well when you have a 1:1 correspondence between XML and JSON and you don't mind having some weird looking JSON  exposed to the client (to respect the chosen standard).

Based on the details you provided I'm assuming that you already have a natural JSON representation and you don't have a 1:1 correspondence since a `FirstName` XML element maps to `First` in JSON.

Your application sits between the JSON client and the SOAP external storage so in  this case the most controllable way would be to work with objects in your application and have two representations for the objects: JSON and XML.

Your client sends a JSON request, you unmarshal that to a request object, marshal the object to XML, send it to the SOAP storage, you get result as XML that you unmarshal to a response object that you now marshal to a JSON response that you finally send back to the client. By using an object in-between you could use [JAXB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding) for the XML representation and something like [Jackson's support for JAXB annotation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations) for JSON.

Either way, doing it manually or using an existing library, you have to map from XML to JSON.